# Uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Coders::Hstore (NameError) [hstore with PG/Rails 3.2.11]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hstore

I have a Rails 3.2.11 app to which I tried adding Postgres Hstore using the `activerecord-postgres-hstore` gem. The app works find in development with PG-9.1.9 db, but gives the following error in the production server with PG-9.1.8 db:`uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Coders::Hstore (NameError)`

The log files are as follows:

**unicorn.log**

```
E, [2013-06-24T18:48:27.379430 #901] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 16706 exit 1> worker=1
I, [2013-06-24T18:48:27.379703 #901]  INFO -- : worker=1 spawning...
I, [2013-06-24T18:48:27.385576 #16719]  INFO -- : worker=1 spawned pid=16719
I, [2013-06-24T18:48:27.385854 #16719]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
E, [2013-06-24T18:48:27.391198 #901] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 16708 exit 1> worker=0
I, [2013-06-24T18:48:27.391379 #901]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawning...
I, [2013-06-24T18:48:27.392775 #16722]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawned pid=16722
I, [2013-06-24T18:48:27.392991 #16722]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
E, [2013-06-24T18:48:29.235072 #16712] ERROR -- : uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Coders::Hstore (NameError)
/home/slaxman/apps/itextbook/releases/20130624183910/app/models/book.rb:7:in `<class:Book>'
/home/slaxman/apps/itextbook/releases/20130624183910/app/models/book.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/slaxman/apps/itextbook/releases/20130624183910/app/admin/books.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

**production.log**

```
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
```

**book.rb**

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base

    serialize :properties , ActiveRecord::Coders::Hstore
    serialize :bookmark_count , ActiveRecord::Coders::Hstore

    attr_accessible :title, :content, :input_method, :bookmarks_attributes, :bookmark_count, :properties


    has_many :bookmarks
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :bookmarks, allow_destroy: true
end
```

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.11'
# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

group :production do
        gem 'pg', '0.14.1'
        gem 'therubyracer','0.11.4'
        gem 'execjs', '1.4.0'
end


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
        gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.6'
        gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 2.2.1'
        gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.2'
        gem 'uglifier', '~> 1.3.0'
        gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.3.1.2'
        gem 'bootswatch-rails', '~> 0.5.0'
end

gem 'unicorn', '~> 4.6.2'
gem 'capistrano', '~> 2.14.2'
gem "multi_json", "~> 1.2.0"
gem 'devise' , '~> 2.2.3'
gem 'cancan', '~> 1.6.8'
gem 'kaminari', '~> 0.14.1'
gem 'kramdown', '~> 0.14.1'
gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.5.6'
gem 'colorbox-rails', '~> 0.0.9'
gem 'coderay', '~> 1.0.8'
gem 'mercury-rails', '~> 0.9.0'
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 0.8.0'
gem 'fog', '~> 1.9.0'
gem 'activeadmin', '~> 0.5.1'
gem 'meta_search', '~> 1.1.3'
gem 'pg_hstore', '~> 0.0.1'
gem "activerecord-postgres-hstore", "~> 0.7.6"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does the fix in this bug help? https://github.com/brainspec/enumerize/issues/42

Comment: @zengr: Tried that. It didn't work in my case though.

Comment: are you requiring 'activerecord-postgres-hstore' anywhere?

Comment: I have included the `activerecord-postgres-hstore` gem in my Gemfile (which I have now shown above)

Comment: right, but I think that somewhere you need to require it, as in `require 'activerecord-postgres-hstore'` perhaps in your config/application.rb after rails but before your your app loads.

Comment: I tried that. But it gives me an error again. I have put the `ActiveRecord::Coders::Hstore` class in lib with the directory structure that Rails expects i.e. `lib/active_record/coders/hstore.rb`. Further, I had to directly autoload it using `ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths << "#{config.root}/lib"` (Autoloading using `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)` did not work. It now gives me an error saying `pg_hstore not found`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the solution was pretty straight forward. I initialized the hstore to an empty array and the issue was solved.

**book.rb**

```
serialize :bookmark_count , ActiveRecord::Coders::Hstore.new({})
serialize :bookmark_count , ActiveRecord``::Coders::Hstore.new({})
```

Comment: As of today with Rails 4.1.4 and Postgres 9.1.13 this does not work (furthermore I don't understand your code)

Answer (score 0):

**Rails 4 and above**

If you are using Rails 4 you don't need [**`activerecord-postgres-hstore`**](https://github.com/diogob/activerecord-postgres-hstore) gem as ActiveRecord 4 provides `HStore` type support

Change

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :properties , ActiveRecord::Coders::Hstore
  serialize :bookmark_count , ActiveRecord::Coders::Hstore
end
```

to

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  # You don't need it anymore
  # serialize :properties , ActiveRecord::Coders::Hstore
  # serialize :bookmark_count , ActiveRecord::Coders::Hstore
end
```

Read it [here](https://github.com/diogob/activerecord-postgres-hstore)